# Eclipse Mqtt paho throws java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes

Tags: mqtt, securityexception, paho, meta-inf

I am using `mqtt` as a client to get messagaes from the mqtt broker.
    Previously I had 0.2.1 which had a issue in clientId generation (greater than 23 characters would fail)

I saw the fix is done in later versions, so I upgraded to 1.0.1. I downloaded the 1.0.1 jar from the below repository

```
eclipse repo [/content/repositories/paho-releases/org/eclipse/paho/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3/1.0.1/]
```

I get: `Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attribute`

I googled and found solutions to fix the issue. I removed the META-INF and zipped the jar again. It solved my problem for the time being. But this should not be done as I understand.

I had found other fixes which didn't help, such as putting the below configuration in my pom.

```
<pre>
    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
</pre>
```

Later I ran `jarsigner -verify org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.0.1.jar`

I got the following:

```
jar verified.

Warning: 
This jar contains entries whose signer certificate will expire within six months.
```

The signer certificate expiring in 6 months.

I am not sure if I should be downloading the same jar or not.

Comment: It's unclear exactly what your question is. Perhaps this is something you should report to the package maintainer?

Comment: I did put this question on eclipse forum also. But as they didn't reply yet, hence was wondering if someone might have already faced this issue. My question is am I downloading a wrong jar or in a wrong way that I am facing these issues (1)  If I do not remove the META_INF from zip : I get Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attribute, 2) the jar's certificate expiring in 6 months )

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense. I'm not an Eclipse guy so I'm clueless on this one -- my hunch is that you're not doing anything wrong on your end, but hopefully someone more familiar with Eclipse can provide more help.

Comment: Thanks Nate. I have raised a bug on eclipse paho for the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
Eclipse packages as and puts osgi bundles in their maven repo.
This is how I made it work:
```

- download mqtt jar & pom from eclipse repo
        https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases/org/eclipse/paho/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3/
- download all its dependencies
- unjar the jar
- From META-INF/MANIFEST.MF remove all lines apart from first 3

  ```
  Manifest-Version: 1.0 Bundle-Localization: bundle
  Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: J2SE-1.4
  ```

  - Remove the certificates in META-INF folder
  - now jar all the unjared files to the same jar name
  - Upload in your maven repo

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late, but I was able to fix the problem by renaming the .class file which contained all of the MQTT stuff. I had originally named it `MQTTListener`. The moment I renamed it `MQTTCommunicationModule` (I know the new name is not great, it was only to verify my suspicion) the error went away.

My guess is I had given the class the same name as a class in the MQTT library which caused the conflict.

**TL;DR**: The error may be caused by creating a class with the same name as a class in the library.